# How can I fit a smoother to a 2-dimensional parametric curve (with R)?

Tags: r, time-series, nonlinear-regression, smoothing, multivariate-regression

I have a dataset of GPS traces of lat/lon and time for some routes (ex: NYC-Boston). Since I have multiple traces for each route, I would like to find the "average" trace, or some kind of smoothed version of all the traces of a given route. It is not a standard regression problem, as the function I need to estimate is not bijective (the traces can form complex shapes like circles, spirals, etc.).
How can I model this data?

Options I have considered so far:

- Kalman/Particle filter: works well to smooth one trace at a time, but not clear how to combine multiple traces of the same route together. Also I would rather have a simpler solution if possible.
- Regress one of the coordinates on the other and time, for example latitude ~ s(longitude, time): could work but seems very hackish, and I don't like the fact that it's not symmetrical w.r.t. the coordinates.
- Model as a multivariate time series: my best guess so far, but not sure it's the right one and how to go about it exactly since the series is not stationary, and there are multiple instances of the same series. Make it a multivariate regression of (lat/lon) ~ s(time)? maybe, but not sure how.

Any suggestions or pointers? Even good key words to search for a methods would be great (searching for *parametric curve fitting* clearly doesn't give the right thing).

[image: example of traces from one route]

Comment: can you show a sample plot?

Comment: @Aksakal I just added an example plot to illustrate the problem!

Comment: This is worth than I thought it would look like.

Comment: What is this "average trace" intended to represent?  Knowledge of your intention is crucial for identifying a meaningful solution.

Comment: Would something like a Bezier Curve help (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Maybe you could somehow find the 'ideal' one for each using squared errors?

Comment: @whuber, the way I see it is that I have many traces that can be seen as noisy version of one true, typical trace. I would like to estimate this underlying trace...

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be the one true trace unless all pilots are given that true route to follow. It seems the pilots are simply flying from the point to point picking their own trace. If there was a true trace you could construct a model accordingly

Comment: The actual existence of a "real trace" might be questionable, I agree with you @Aksakal, but you can argue the same for most applications of regressions in practice... Similar to a regression, you can see the problem as something like "observed trace" = "standard trace" + "noise", where the goal is to recover "standard trace" from a dataset of "observed traces".

Comment: In regression if your model is wrong the results won’t be good.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to interpret your data as directed graph. The direction for the traces will be given by the start- and endpoints of each route (e.g. NYC->Boston). The nodes will be represented by (lat/long). The order of the nodes is defined by the timestamp.

Consider the following three traces

Trace A: Start->A->B->C->End

Trace B: Start->A->B->C->End

Trace C: Start->A->D->B->E->End

Then you can calculate the transition probabilities for each node to all other connected nodes (edges):

- Start->A : 1
- A->B : 2/3
- A->D : 1/3
- B->C : 2/3
- B->E : 1/3
- C->End : 1
- D->B : 1
- E->End: 1

If you follow the most probable transitions, you will get the most probable path.

However, circles might need some further investigation, as far as there are edges to previous visited nodes. Then you might extend the transition probability to two or more edges in the form of "A->B->C".

Here are some other pointers:

- transition probabilities:R-package markovchain
- https://kateto.net/network-visualization
- you can compare paths by their igraph::mean_distance()

Comment: Thanks, I'll explore this idea. The problem that I see, though, is that 
1) it requires to discretize the entire space (possible to do, but definitely loses resolution)
2) my time stamps are not at regular intervals

Answer (score 1):

I would first connect all coordinates of each trace with lines, or smoother curves. Then I would parameterize the curve by length (distance) from the starting point along the trace. So that half the way on a given path would be 0.5, for instance, i.e. normalized distances.

Once this is done for all traces, then it's easy to average lat/lon for any given length (distance) from the start. I’m afraid this is the only non parametric way that matches the problem. From your plot it appears that the traces don’t try to stay on a certain path but rather fly from point A to point B on the path of their choosing.

Comment: Good hack idea, I'll give it a try. I'd prefer to have something that does a proper smoothing of the whole trace, if possible, but this is definitely worth a try.

Comment: You will need to normalize the distances, so that the distance is a fraction of one. This way you can average different length paths

Comment: good point, I was actually considering something like time warping, which would be very similar to that.

Comment: Since you are averaging in space the distance is a better parameter unless the speed is constant

Comment: Here’s another idea: instead of getting one average at each point, g estimate the distribution. In this case if there are two or more attractors you’ll catch them. In your plot it seems there are two major routes that are most popular